# Angular error only when published by VS2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I receive the below error when running a production build of an Angular 6 app under IIS (Win10 Pro).  The app is published using VS2017 15.8.  If I run `ng serve --prod` for the same project/app there error is not there.  I just updated VS2017 yesterday, so Im leaning on something broke.  Any ideas?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was caused by the Angular build optimizer.  In order to fix it, I had to set `buildOptimizer` to false in the angular.json

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after VS update. Solved by simple npm cache clean (verify) and npm install.
Check this [link](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/2570)